# Function reads max and min int value, returns it - with text string

Tags: c++

I got a function that returns a number. However it seems like there's something I do wrong when using the function, before I didn't use it like a pointer - but how do I do that?

'read': none of the 2 overloads could convert all argument types is the error I'm getting.

Here's the code:

```
int nr = read("This is a test", 0000, 9999);
cout << nr;

int read(char* t, int min, int max) {
    int number;
    do {
        cout << '\t' << t << " (" << min << '-' << max << "):  ";
        cin >> number;  cin.ignore();
    } while (number < min || number > max);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: A string literal is a constant array. It decays to a `const char*`.

Comment: Make `read` take a `const char *` and then you can go on to your next problem.

Comment: in your snippet there is only one overload, is it possible that you have more code than that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the error message in more detail you will probably see something like "cannot convert argument 1 from "const char*" to "char*".

String literals have the type "const char*" so your read method needs to be:

```
int read(const char* t, int min, int max) {
```

Comment: String literals have the type `const char[n]` where `n` is the size. It only decays to a pointer like any other array. Otherwise the answer is correct.

Comment: Error message is "'read' none of the 2 overloadws could convert all t he argument types". Still getting that even though I changed to const

Comment: If you post the full message or tell us the compiler we might be able to help

Comment: Pretty much given the whole code in the text above, but here:
`#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int read(const char* t, int min, int max);

int main() {

 int nr = read("This is a test", 0000, 9999);
 cout << nr;

 return 0;
}

int read(const char* t, int min, int max) {
 int number;
 do {
  cout << '\t' << t << " (" << min << '-' << max << "):  ";
  cin >> number;  cin.ignore();
 } while (number < min || number > max);
 return number;
}`

Comment: that code compiles for me... I was asking for the full error message and the compiler you are using though. Most compilers would give more details than that

Comment: @Ultralight get rid of `using namespace std;`.  It only [causes problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)